# How can i get the time interval in python

Tags: python

Now I have time :`a=2015-02-23 03:56:00   b=2015-02-23 02:56:00`  and many time in `c`
how can I select the the time which are involved in this period

```
for d in c :

  if (a >= d>= b):

     print d
```

my result:

```
2015-02-23 13:09:00

2015-02-23 12:09:00

2015-02-23 12:09:00
```

the result is wrong!!!why??thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.strptime("2015-02-23 02:56:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end = datetime.strptime("2015-02-23 03:56:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

if start <= d <= end:
    print(d)
```

I also renamed your variables to make it a little more obvious, your time needs to be >= the start time and <= the end time to be in the range.

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime 
In [2]: start = datetime.strptime("2015-02-23 02:56:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

In [3]: end = datetime.strptime("2015-02-23 03:56:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

In [4]: d = datetime.strptime("2015-02-23 13:09:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

In [5]: start <= d <= end
Out[5]: False

In [6]: d = datetime.strptime("2015-02-23 12:09:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

In [7]: start <= d <= end
Out[7]: False

In [8]: d = datetime.strptime("2015-02-23 02:59:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

In [9]: start <= d <= end
Out[9]: True
```

Comment: 2015-02-23 13:09:00
      2015-02-23 12:09:00
the  result is still wrong

Comment: are these actually datetimes?

Comment: Yes, what exactly are a,b  and d?

Comment: it is datetime object

Comment: The code in my answer will find all times in the range start - end

Comment: may I have one more question?

Comment: d = datetime.strptime("xxxxxx","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") can xxxxx be a variable?

Comment: yes, that creates a datetime object from each `d` once the format is always the same so you can pass `d` if it is a string

Comment: if I write this:    datetime.strptime(start,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Comment: there is a error message: TypeError: must be string, not datetime.datetime

Comment: if it is already a datetime object just use each `d` without converting.